# Django - Inserting related instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, save

I am trying to change how a model saves and add a field automatically. The field in question is a foreignkey.

here is the code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    season = Season.objects.order_by('start')[0]
    self.season = season
```

But it doesn't add anything...

It says success but it doesn't add....

EDIT:
Full code:

```
class Team(models.Model):

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('F', 'Féminin'),
    ('M', 'Masculin'),
)

name = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name="nom")
slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True,populate_from='name')
season = models.ForeignKey(Season,verbose_name="saison",editable=False)
association = models.ForeignKey(Association,verbose_name="association")
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,verbose_name="catégorie")
division = models.ForeignKey(Division,verbose_name="division")
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,verbose_name="sexe")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Équipe'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Équipes'

def __str__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    season = Season.objects.order_by('start')[0]
    self.season = season
    super(self,Team).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the end of your ‘save‘ method you must call the superclass ‘save‘:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    season = Season.objects.order_by('start')[0]
    self.season = season
    super(MyModelName,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi, I get this: must be type, not Team. I am going to edit the first post to show the whole model.

Comment: I have exchanged the two arguments of super. See the corrected code.